# Putting image in table using innerHTML (Javascript / Html)

Tags: javascript

Alright, some information right off the bat, I have a table that is dynamically being created.
The table looks roughly like this :

|item__  | price | category | category | category | category | picture |

|chicken| $20   | _______ |_ ______        | _______        | _______        | 1000.png|

```
        var array = csvpls();
        var table = "<tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if (j == 6) {
                table += "<td>" + "<img src='CSV_Photos/" + array[i][j] +"'style ='width:500px;height:300px'>";
                } else if {
                table += "<td>" + array[i][j];
                }
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "</tr>";
        }

    document.getElementById("Invtable").innerHTML = table;
```

This is the code that I have at the moment, where array is a 2D array. And every (6th column in the row, I want it to be an image) When runned, this does not display any table whatsoever.

In the code below

```
        var array = csvpls();
        var table = "<tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                table += "<td>" + array[i][j];
                }
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "</tr>";
        }

    document.getElementById("Invtable").innerHTML = table;
```

Without the if statement and the additional img content, the table displays perfectly, but obviously 1000.png shows up instead of the actual image.
CSV_Photos is a folder where the image is stored at, essentially in the same folder. I don't know what is wrong, any help or leads are appreciated.

Edit: So the 2nd part of the code I have works perfectly, It generates a table for me. But at every 6th column of a row is a picture name (1000.png) and its in the folder CSV_Photo. I want it to no display as 1000.png, but instead the picture. The 1st section of code is my attempt to make it an image, but no table is created so I'm guessing there is something wrong with this line table += "" + <"img src= 'CSV_Photos/" + array[i][j] +"'style ='width:500px;height:300px'>";

Comment: Can you please share your array data? and what did you got as result?

Comment: It is just a huge 2D array [98][6]. Like I mentioned the 2nd part of the code, it generates a table perfectly, but at every 6th column is the name of a picture. I don't want the name, but the actual picture in the table. So the 1st part of the code is what I tried to do, but when it ran, nothing shows up.

Comment: Try the code in my answer, I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several problems in your code that needs to be fixed :

- You are not appending the `td` elements inside the `tr` but directly
  inside the `table`, you need to move the  line `table += "<tr>";`
  before the nested loop.
- And you are not specifying closing tags for `<td>` elements so when
  you include the `img` tag it will mess up the layout.
- Another thing just inverse the use of `"` and `'` in your `img` tag
  definition because HTML uses `".."` to define attributes.

Here's how should be your code:

```
var array = csvpls();
var table = "<tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  table += "<tr>";
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    if (j == 6) {
      table += "<td>" + '<img src="CSV_Photos/' + array[i][j] + '" style ="width:500px;height:300px"></td>';
    } else if {
      table += "<td>" + array[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
  }
  table += "</tr>";
}

document.getElementById("Invtable").innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: The issue still occurs. When I tested out your code, but removing  if (j == 6) {
      table += "<td>" + '<img src="CSV_Photos/' + array[i][j] + '" style ="width:500px;height:300px"></td>';
    } else if {. It creates a table perfectly, but obviously the name of the image appears not the picture. But when I used the code you had there, nothing happens, in fact the table does not even appear anymore.

Comment: Fixed my issue The line was like so : table += "<td> <img src='CSV_Photos/" + array[i][j] + "' style ='width:300px;height:300px'> </td>"; But, you're code helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I got it, in fact `var table = "<tr>";` should be `var table = "<table>";`, I didn't saw that in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    var array = csvpls();
    var table = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";

        for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            table += "<td>" + array[i][j];
        }

        table += "</tr>";
    }
    table += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("Invtable").innerHTML = table;
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you wanted the image to be on the 2nd row, 3rd cell the condition should be:

> ```
> if (i === 1 && j === 2) {...
> ```

- If you want the whole 2nd row with the same image in each cell then it should be:

> ```
> if (i === 1) {...
> ```

- If you want a entire 3rd column to have the same image then it would be:

> ```
> if (j === 2) {...
> ```

- If it's a different image for every cell, then name each file by table coordinates like this...

> ```
> img1-2.png
> ```

...then change the string that renders an image inside a cell as:

> ```
>  table += `<td><img src='http://imgh.us/img${i}-${j}.png' style ='width:50px;height:50px'></td>`
> ```

- ***Or*** if I understand correctly, the array already has the filenames. If that's true, then the string should be...

> ```
>  table += `<td><img src='http://imgh.us/${array[i][j]}' style ='width:50px;height:50px'></td>`
> ```

... and the array would be something like this:

> ```
>   var array = [
>       ['rt','AD','1000.png','uy','ii'],
>       ['rt','AD','1001.png','uy','ii'],
>       ['rt','AD','1002.png','uy','ii']
>     ];
> ```

BTW, I had to do some changes to the code in order for it to work since it's only a partial code you provided, but the gist of it is the condition of course.

Also you'll notice the strange  syntax of the strings, that's [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or "strings on steroids".

### Demo

```js
var array = cvpls();
var table = ``;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  table += `<tr>`;
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    if (i === 1 && j === 2) {
      table += `<td><img src='http://imgh.us/statik.gif' style ='width:50px;height:50px'></td>`;
    } else {
      table += `<td>${array[i][j]}</td>`;
    }
  }
  table += `</tr>`;
  document.getElementById("Invtable").innerHTML = table;
}

function cvpls() {
  return array = [
    [4, 5, 6, 9, 2],
    ['img', 'img', 'img', 'img', 'img'],
    ['d', 'b', 'g', 'i', 'o']
  ];
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table id='Invtable'></table>
```

Comment: The image is in every 6th column of a row. So for example [0][6] is an image, 1[6] is an image. I believe the problem is in the way I formatted the line for the image to appear. Which is  table += "<td>" + "<img src='CSV_Photos/" + array[i][j] +"'style ='width:500px;height:300px'>"; The array at [i][j] should be the name of my image for example "1000.png".

Comment: I'd name the images as to where it belongs within the table. Of course it might be to your advantage your way, but I don't know what `csvpls()` does or what it really returns. @DaNubCake See update.

Comment: @DaNubCake See newest update, I think I know what you mean now.